# Upgrade and move Sonar Server 2.13.1 -> 4.5.6LTS - Before starting

Tags: sonarqube

on a production server RHEL 6.3 (Box1) run Jenkins ver. 1.565.1 (sonar plugin 2.1); Maven  ver. 3.0.5; Java ver. 1.7.0_51; Mysql ver. 5.1.61 (InnoDB engine); SonarQube ver. 2.13.1 (No Sonar Plugin are used).

I would like to upgrade Sonar 2.13.1 to Sonar 4.5.6 as it's the last LTS
Then the upgrade process will be the following: from 2.13.1 -> 3.7.4 -> 4.5.6 (two steps)?

Plus, Sonar will be moved/upgraded on a different box (Box2) and mysqlDB on a third one (Box3).

Related questions:

- Will Data be preserved doing a dump/restore?
- Can I have Box3 on a dedicated production DB network: 192.x.x.x (while Box1 and Box2 will be in the same - 172.x.x.x) or is mandatory to have them on the same network? Alternatively would be better have Box2 = Box3 or none of the two configurations?

Extra question:
Upgraded version of the official documentation shows that Analizers doesn't talk with Sonar DB while a previous version states they do. This means that from a certain Sonar version the behavior changes and this does not impact the upgrade process?

Thank you,
Leonardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upgrade directly from 2.13.1 to 4.5.6. It's only after 4.5.6 that you must hit every LTS between your current version and your target version.

Moving the DB to a different box: Follow your DB vendor's recommendation for moving the DB to a different machine, then connect your SQ server to the DB at its new location & make sure everything looks right. That should be it. You can do the upgrade before or after the move, just make sure - as stated in the normal upgrade procedure - that you back up your DB first.

Proximity on the network of analysis and DB boxes: The tie to the database during analysis was only fully cut in 5.2. Since you're only upgrading to 4.5.6, you'll want to keep these two boxes close to each other, network-wise. Note that I'm referring to the machine on which analysis runs, as distinct from the one running the server.